# sqoop-merge returns error on null key

Tags: sqoop

```
sqoop merge --merge-key emp_uid \
 --new-data /user/emp_new \
 --onto /user/emp \
 --target-dir /user/emp_stage \
 --class-name emp_data \
 --jar-file /tmp/sqoop-user/compile/emp_data.jar \
```

But it fails with the error:

```
Cannot join values on null key. Did you specify a key column that exists?
```

Checked to see if the primary key was right and it was.

Comment: indentation for code

Comment: @Venkat : Did you find the soultion for this?

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using a directory for --new-date and --onto? These should point to some data files

Comment: The directory has part files and I need the merge on all the files in both the directories